# Web3 method getTransactionReceipt() does not return token transfer value for particular token transaction

Tags: web3js, transactions, tokens, receipts, explorer-api

I've tested [getTransactionReceipt()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt), to get all detail about transaction with amount of token transfer. Also tested [getTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction) but it returns only Ether transferred value. Is there any other method using which I can get amount of token transferred?

Comment: Tokens are not native and are controlled by a smart contract. You have to check the events emitted by the particular smart contract to know the amount of tokens transferred.

Comment: @SanjaySB, it means that the web3 methods will returns native information onlu i.e address?